# Let Googlebot crawl my Ajax website in this way?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, seo

I'm searching for SEO ways for my ajax website for a while. I know there are several ways to handle that but i wonder if my solution will work.

So if i have index.html like that.

```
<header>
    <a href="/otherpage" class="ajax-load">Link to other page</a>
</header>
```

Then check if it's not Google bot and replace href with ajax link.

```
var isGoogleBot = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('googlebot') > 0;

//Check if it's not Google Bot
if( !isGoogleBot ) {
    //Convert link to ajax link
    $('.ajax-load').each(function(i,el){
        var href = $(el).attr('href');
        $(el).attr('href', '#' + href);
    });
}
```

In "/otherpage" directory i'll create and index.php file contains:

```
<?php 
    include("../header.php");
    include("content.php");
    include("../footer.php");
?>
```

So, if it's a Google bot link won't change and bot will crawl http://example.com/otherpage (which is generated by php), and if it's a real user i will only load content.php to my wrapper through ajax without jump.

Does it work?

Comment: Dont know, try it and let us all know

Comment: @RiggsFolly, I don't have any Apache hosting to run PHP now. I'll make a decision to stay static hosting or move to a server depends on this question. But if i have, i will let you know.

Comment: Why don't you just specify in `<noscript></noscript>`? Googlbot will get into that, according to my experience.

Comment: @Sina , Googlebot runs javascript for a while. Check this out [link](http://searchengineland.com/tested-googlebot-crawls-javascript-heres-learned-220157)